# Loop over list of images uri and generate deployment in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kustomize

I have list of images that have similar deployment specs but different repository uri i want to deploy them on k8 cluster, i am using FluxCD, i am open to use any k8s tool.

Answer (score 0):

Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72685289/kubernetes-yml-use-for-loop/72686070#72686070) help? It's a similar use case (looping over items to produce similar specs)

Comment: any way to do this with kustomize ? thanx

Comment: I'm no expert on Kustomize but everything I'd read seems to imply it is far more limiting than Helm, so I would lean towards "no".